# Migration from custom multiprocessing solution to dask

Tags: dask

We have a relatively complex scientific model (https://github.com/OGGM/oggm/), which uses a home-cooked multiprocessing solution which splits work into so-called entity tasks.

Each entity-task operates on a GlacierDirectory, called gdir.
It's quite literally representing a directory on disk, with all the data for that glacier in it.
Each entity task then downloads (from the internet, if necessary and not yet present) the raw data files, opens them or files from previous entity tasks, processes it, and writes it to a new file in the gdir.

This obviously is not very efficient and does not scale well over more than a single machine.
On top of that, the model has A TON of global variables and state. I have already started working on putting all that global state into a main OGGM class, so instead of global state you have all that state in an instance of the main OGGM class.

Now I would like to replace all the multiprocessing we manually do at the moment (see https://github.com/OGGM/oggm/blob/master/oggm/workflow.py#L104 for the main function).
I cannot migrate the entire model at once, so some kind of slow transition is needed.

My current idea is to start with replacing our current entity_task model with dask, with minimal modifications to the tasks themselves.

For that, I my idea is to modify our entity_task wrapper to always return the gdir it got as input, so that chaining multiple entity tasks can be done by giving the (delayed) return value of the previous one as input to the next one.

Now for the actual question...
The Dask documentation mentions in multiple places not to mutate inputs(https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-best-practices.html#don-t-mutate-inputs). However, I would very much be mutating the input gdir, and even returning it in its mutated form.
Calling copy(gdir) for every entity-task seems quite wasteful, specially when in the future I would start to actually store data in there, instead of writing it to and then reading it back from disk.
What is the proper way to handle this?

Each gdir also has/will have a reference to the oggm instance, which is where what currently is the global state will be stored. That seems problematic to me when we start distributing tasks across multiple physical nodes. Will it keep copying our formally global state for every function call? Will it realize it's all the same instance, and only copy it once to each worker process?
What happens when it gets changed between different entity_tasks? With them being now delayed, the changed might be lost, and we need a new helper-entity-task, with takes gdir as input, modifies the oggm instance state via it, and returns the gdir again.
Which brings me back to the question of mutating the input object of a delayed function.

Any help regarding this migration is very welcome, I have very little experience with Dask and just going by the documentation and examples so far has proven very challenging.

Comment: I encourage you to engage the Pangeo community.  https://discourse.pangeo.io/

Comment: You might want to take a look into [Actors](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/actors.html) for the stateful portions; as for the other tidbits, after glancing at the repository I'm not qualified to comment on the subject area but having refactored code bases in the past I would just recommend plentiful unit tests (doc tests are nice too) and start small. Good luck!